# Blackberry Twitter client

Tags: blackberry, twitter, xauth

I just want to tweet on my own wall from my Blackberry application. xAuth would be the best way to have seamless UI integartion. But unfortunately, I'm not able to get it work.. I tried twitter_api_me-1.3 which has xAuth implementation but it gives me 401 error while validating with parameters specified at  http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth.

Can anyone please confirm if those keys and secret are still valid and are xAuth enabled?
I'm running short of time. Any help would be real great.

Answer (score 0):

The application works well if you provide new/own key and secret.

Answer (score 0):

Has your application been approved to use [xAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth)?  Until you are, you won't be able to authenticate successfully.  From the linked document:

> xAuth access is restricted to approved applications. If your application is a desktop or mobile application and the standard web OAuth flow or PIN-code out-of-band flow is not right for you, send a detailed message to api@twitter.com to request xAuth privileges. Include the name of your application, the consumer key, the application ID (if available), and a summary of how xAuth is best-suited for your application.